# lookup values in table

Tags: r, match, lookup-tables

I have the following table:

```
  table(dta$recipient,dta$treat)>0

                 1     2     3     4     5     6
      couple  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
      female FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
      male   FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

And I also have a variable dta$treat_new that contains a permutation of dta$treat. How can I make a variable dta$recipient_new with the corresponding values for recipient? Note that levels(dta$recipient) and levels(dta$treat) may change. So the expected output would be a new variable like dta$recipient:

```
> head(dta$recipient_new)
[1] male female male couple male male
Levels: couple female male
```

that corresponds to dta$treat_new

```
> head(dta$treat_new)
[1] 5 3 6 1 5 6
```

Here is a reproducible example:

```
set.seed(12345)
recipient <- rep(c("male","female"), times=2)

treat <- rep(1:4, times=2)
df <- data.frame(recipient,treat)

table(df$recipient, df$treat)

df$treat_perm <- sample(treat)

df$treat_perm
[1] 2 3 1 4 2 1 3 4
```

I want to know how to get the corresponding recipients, so:

```
df$recipient_perm
[1] female male male female female male male female
```

Comment: Isn't it just `df$recipient[df$treat_perm]`

Comment: Seems like you just want to shuffle the data rows. Does this give you what you are looking for? `df[sample(nrow(df)),]`